# ListView is not updating when adapter is set

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView named lvSongs inside a fragment which will be updated by an action in another fragment. The method which updates is called fine, and it populates an ArrayList in order to be used as data handler for the adapter. I create a new instance of ArrayAdapter and here comes the problem: when I set it to my ListView, it does not update. I'm using AndroidAnnotations. Code below:

fragment_song_view.xml

```
...
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btSyncSongs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btSyncSongs" >
    </ListView>
...
```

SongViewFragment.java

```
    package fragment;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
    import org.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
    import org.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;
    import org.androidannotations.annotations.InstanceState;
    import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import myproject.MainActivity;
    import myproject.R;
    import myproject.connector.JoinTagSongConnector;
    import myproject.connector.SongConnector;
    import myproject.connector.TagConnector;
    import myproject.model.JoinTagSong;
    import myproject.model.Song;
    import myproject.model.Tag;
    import myproject.util.ChooseFoldersActivity_;
    import myproject.util.UtilDialog;

    @EFragment(R.layout.fragment_song_view)
        private SongConnector songConn;

        private Song curSong;

        private String[] folderPathsToSync;

        private List<Song> songs;

        private ArrayAdapter<Song> adapter;

        private Tag defaultTag = null;

        private TagConnector tagConn;

        private JoinTagSongConnector jtsConn;

        @ViewById
        protected ListView lvSongs;

        @Click
        protected void btPreviousSong() {
    //unimportant
        }

        @Click
        protected void btPlayPause() {
    //unimportant
        }

        private void toastShow(String text, int duration) {
    //unimportant; shows a toast with defined message and duration
        }

        @Click
        protected void btNextSong() {
    //unimportant
        }

        protected MediaPlayer mp;

        @InstanceState
        String[] values;

    //this is called after onCreate, which is implemented automatically by AndroidAnnotations
        @AfterViews
        public void init() {
            if (jtsConn == null)
                jtsConn = new JoinTagSongConnector(getActivity());
            if (tagConn == null)
                tagConn = new TagConnector(getActivity());
            folderPathsToSync = new Intent().getStringArrayExtra("folderPathsToSync");
            if (songConn == null)
                songConn = new SongConnector(getActivity());
            if (values == null) {
                loadListView();
            } else {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout,
                        R.id.textView, values);
                lvSongs.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            setLvSongsAttrs();
        }

        @Click
        public void btSelectFolders() {
    //unimportant
        }

        public void updateListView(List<Tag> tags) {
            List<Song> aux = songConn.findAll();
            if (tags.size() != 0) {
                List<Song> filteredSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
                for (Song song : aux) {
                    if (song.containsTags(tags)) {
                        if (!filteredSongs.contains(song))
                            filteredSongs.add(song);
                    }
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.textView,
                        filteredSongs);
            } else {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.textView, aux);
            }
            lvSongs.setAdapter(adapter);
            setLvSongsAttrs();
        }

        @Click
        public void btSyncSongs() {
    //unimportant   
    }

        private class PositiveClickListener implements OnClickListener {
            //unimportant
        }

        private void loadListView() {
            this.songs = this.songConn.findAll();
            this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.textView, this.songs);
            this.lvSongs.setAdapter(this.adapter);
            setLvSongsAttrs();
        }

        private void setLvSongsAttrs() {
            lvSongs.setOnItemLongClickListener(new SongLongClickListener());
            lvSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener());
        }

        private class ItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    //unimportant
        }

        private void stopAndPlay(Song song) {
    //      unimportant
        }

        private void loadListView(Song song) {
//unimportant       }

        public class SongLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {
    //unimportant
        }

        public ArrayList<File> synchronize(File file) {
    //unimportant
        }
    }
```

[EDIT 1]===============================
I changed implementation to what @michal.z said, but still not updating... Code below:

```
@AfterViews
    public void init() {
        if (jtsConn == null)
            jtsConn = new JoinTagSongConnector(getActivity());
        if (tagConn == null)
            tagConn = new TagConnector(getActivity());
        folderPathsToSync = new Intent().getStringArrayExtra("folderPathsToSync");
        if (songConn == null)
            songConn = new SongConnector(getActivity());
        loadListView();
    }


    private void loadListView() {
        this.songs = this.songConn.findAll();
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.textView,
                this.songs);
        this.lvSongs.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        lvSongs.setOnItemLongClickListener(new SongLongClickListener());
        lvSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener());
    }
public void updateListView(List<Tag> tags) {
        adapter.clear();
        List<Song> aux = songConn.findAll();
        if (tags.size() != 0) {
            List<Song> filteredSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
            for (Song song : aux) {
                if (song.containsTags(tags)) {
                    if (!filteredSongs.contains(song)) {
                        filteredSongs.add(song);
                        adapter.add(song);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (Song song : aux) {
                adapter.add(song);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

[EDIT 2]=============================

```
@AfterViews
public void init() {
        if (jtsConn == null)
            jtsConn = new JoinTagSongConnector(getActivity());
        if (tagConn == null)
            tagConn = new TagConnector(getActivity());
        folderPathsToSync = new Intent().getStringArrayExtra("folderPathsToSync");
        if (songConn == null)
            songConn = new SongConnector(getActivity());
        loadListView();
    }

    private void loadListView() {
        this.songs = this.songConn.findAll();
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Song>(getActivity(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.textView,
                this.songs);
        this.lvSongs.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        lvSongs.setOnItemLongClickListener(new SongLongClickListener());
        lvSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener());
    }

    public void updateListView(List<Tag> tags) {
        songs.clear();
        List<Song> aux = songConn.findAll();
        if (tags.size() != 0) {
            List<Song> filteredSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
            for (Song song : aux) {
                if (song.containsTags(tags)) {
                    if (!filteredSongs.contains(song)) {
                        filteredSongs.add(song);
                        songs.add(song);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            songs.addAll(aux);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use just 1 Adapter. Then your Adapter and Fragment should share a reference to the same ArrayList. On update just set new values in that ArrayList and remember to call `notifydatasetchanged` on Adapter.

Comment: You have to add new songs to ArrayList not to Adapter. If you look into Android source code of ArrayAdapter you will see that constuctor which you use set list which you pass as its internal list. [ArrayAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.init%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.List%29)

Comment: Changed code again... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it still does not update. And in debug I can see that the mObjects array, in ArrayAdapter, only contains one value, but it shows more than that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare Listview object globally from where every class can access it.After that initialize it and set the adapter in the activity class. After that when the listview will be changed call   notifydatasetchanged  method on the object that has been declare globally. Note that do not recreate object.Use it globally.

Hope it helps.